# RightAws::Ec2.new, only per region?

Tags: amazon-ec2, right-aws

This is a question about ruby RightAws API to Amazon EC2. When we create a new instance of Ec2 by RightAws::Ec2.new, passing region or not, all calls to methods using that instance of ec2 thus created, only talk about things inside that region (or default region), is this right? Or, are there calls which are universal, even while passing an explicit region?

Thanks
Udaya